# Azure Data Factory DataFlow Sink to Delta fails when schema changes (column data types and similar)

Tags: delta-lake, azure-data-factory

We have an Azure Data Factory dataflow, it will sink into Delta. We have Owerwrite, Allow Insert options set and Vacuum = 1.
When we run the pipeline over and over with no change in the table structure pipeline is successfull.
But when the table structure being sinked changed, ex data types changed and such the pipeline fails with below error.

Error code: DFExecutorUserError
Failure type: User configuration issue

Details: Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'ConvertToDelta': Job aborted.

[image]

We tried setting Vacuum to 0 and back, Merge Schema set and now, instead of Overwrite Truncate and back and forth, pipeline still failed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try enabling Delta Lake's schema evolution ([more information](https://www.databricks.com/discover/diving-into-delta-lake-talks/schema-enforcement-evolution))?  By default, Delta Lake has schema enforcement enabled which means that the change to the source table is not allowed which would result in an error.

Even with overwrite enabled, unless you specify schema evolution, overwrite will fail because by default the schema cannot be changed.

Comment: Can I enable Delta Lake schema evolution from within Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 0):

I created ADLS Gen2 storage account and created input and output folders and uploaded parquet file into input folder.
I created pipeline and created dataflow as below:

[image]

I have taken Parquet file as source.
Dataflow Source:

[image]

Dataset of Source:

[image]

Data preview of Source:

[image]

I created derived column to change the structure of the table.
Derived column:

[image]

I updated 'difficulty' column of parquet file. I changed the datatype of 'difficulty' column from long to double using below code:

```
difficulty : toDouble(difficulty)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

I updated 'transactions_len' column of parquet file. I changed the datatype of 'transactions_len' column from Integer to float using below code:

```
transactions_len : toFloat(transactions_len)
```

I updated 'number' column of parquet file. I changed the datatype of 'number' column from long to string using below code:

```
number : toString(number)
```

Image for reference:

[image]

Data preview of Derived column:

[image]

I have taken delta as sink.
Dataflow sink:

[image]

Sink settings:

[image]

Data preview of Sink:

[image]

I run the pipeline It executed successfully.

Image for reference:

[image]

I t successfully stored in my storage account output folder.

Image for reference:

[image]

The procedure worked in my machine please recheck from your end.

Comment: When I changed data types to incompatible (ex from string to int or from datetime to int or similar) we get an error. See sample before or after tables below

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableBefore](
 [name] int NOT NULL,
 [schema_id] int NOT NULL,
 [create_date] int NOT NULL,
 [modify_date] int NOT NULL,
 [new_column] varchar(6) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableAfter](
 [name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
 [create_date] datetime NOT NULL,
 [modify_date] datetime NOT NULL,
 [new_column] int NOT NULL
)

Comment: Could you please provide information about whether the source table and destination table is same?

Comment: Table name has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The source (Ingestion) was generated to azure blob with given a specific filename. Whenever we generated to source parquet files without specifying a specific filename but only a directory the sink worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).